# I am trying to create a Tkinter register system, i can add entries, I cannot validate to see if email and password in the same row match

Tags: python, database, sqlite, validation, tkinter

```
connection = sqlite3.connect("login_register_system/user_db")
c = connection.cursor()

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
             ID text,
             Firstname text,
             Lastname text,
             Email text,
             Password text)""")


def login_authenticator():
    e = (emailE.get())
    p = (passwordE.get())
     
    c.execute(f"""SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email=? AND Password=?""", (e, p))
    if e == p in "user_db":
        print("User exists")
    else:
        print("User does not exist")
```

This is just a part of the whole program I am trying to create, I want to know how I can check to see if a user email and password in the same row match, if they do, I can then create an IF statement to create a log in. I am not sure if I'm on the right track.

Comment: `if e == p in "user_db":` is a nonsense statement.  Your SELECT will return nothing if the password doesn't match.  The `c.execute` will return a record set.  You need to check if the recordset is empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More like this:

```
def login_authenticator():
    e = emailE.get()
    p = passwordE.get()
     
    q = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Email=? AND Password=?", (e, p))
    if q.fetchone():
        print("User exists and password matches")
    else:
        print("User does not exist or password does not match")
```

I assume you understand it's a hugely bad idea to store and transmit passwords in the clear like that.

One also might ask why you're using `print` in a tkinter application, but I assume you'll get to that.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful, I used the print function to test whether the values in the table exists or not, I will delete the print and change it once it works, thanks again.